# How to make it visible in github.io for a vue-cli project

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, github-pages, vue-cli

I have created a vue-cli project. 
After I run build it, it works in the http-server. I'd like to push it to my github.io, and I build it as what I found on the Internet. However, at https://tsunaou.github.io/VueJiaogaiFront/dist/index.html  I can only see a blank page and it show like this,nothing in the div whose id is app.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yg62o.png)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're building Github Pages from master. To make this work you'll either need to build into a directory called `docs` (instead of `dist`) and change the settings on your repo to point to `docs`, or move the built files up to the project root.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's in the documentation:

[deployment to github pages](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/deployment.html#github-pages)